# Error 1452 MySQL and NodeJS. How come the database cant reference my table right?

Tags: mysql, node.js, mariadb

So im getting Error 1452 from my Node console when inserting a new user account.
Here is the error

> { Error: ER_NO_REFERENCED_ROW_2: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`myeherlpertst2`.`customers`, CONSTRAINT `customers_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`))
>
> code: 'ER_NO_REFERENCED_ROW_2',
>     errno: 1452,
>     sqlMessage: 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`myeherlpertst2`.`customers`, CONSTRAINT `customers_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`))',
>     sqlState: '23000',
>     index: 0,

Im very sure that the reason I am getting this error is because the customers table is trying to reference something that isnt there BUT I dont understand why its not referencing it. In my Node code below I insert the user table first which auto increments user_id and is not null. Do I have to end the transaction for the first insert and then start a new one before I can insert into the customers table?

```
    connection.beginTransaction(function(error){

    if(error){

    console.log('Error Caught');
    return res;
}

  if (error) {throw error;
    console.log('Error Caught');
    return;}
  connection.query('Insert into users( user_name, user_password, user_type) values (?,?,?)', [customer.body.userName, customer.body.password, userType=1], function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return;
    }
      connection.query('Insert into customers(cust_first_name, cust_last_name, cust_email, cust_city, cust_address, cust_zip_code, cust_state, cust_phone_num, cust_role, cust_website, cust_business_name) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', [customer.body.firstName, customer.body.lastName, customer.body.email, customer.body.city, customer.body.address, customer.body.zipCode, customer.body.state, customer.body.phoneNumber, customer.body.custRole=1, customer.body.website, customer.body.businessName], function (error, results, fields) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
      });
    res.end(JSON.stringify(results));
    });
    console.log('End Transaction')
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `user_id` column correctly in the `customers` table. [MySQL's LAST_INSERT_ID() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) is the source of the value you need. Here's how to do that, in SQL.

```
Insert into users( user_name, user_password, user_type) values (?,?,?);

Insert into customers(user_id, cust_first_name, cust_last_name, cust_email, 
                      cust_city, cust_address, cust_zip_code, cust_state,
                      cust_phone_num, cust_role, cust_website, cust_business_name) 
              values (LAST_INSERT_ID(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);
```

Notice that the insert into the customers table changes the value of LAST_INSERT_ID(), to the value of the autoincrementing ID in that table. So, if you need to reuse the value from the users table, do this, with three queries rather than two:

```
Insert into users( user_name, user_password, user_type) values (?,?,?);

SET @userid := LAST_INSERT_ID();

Insert into customers(user_id, cust_first_name, cust_last_name, cust_email, 
                      cust_city, cust_address, cust_zip_code, cust_state,
                      cust_phone_num, cust_role, cust_website, cust_business_name) 
              values (@userid,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);
```

I'll leave it to you to put the queries into your node program.

Comment: But I thought the foreign key in the customers table is supposed to just link it. I figured the problem is because the data hasn't been written to the database (for whatever reason) that the second statement has foreign key issues.Ill try this but it seems more of workaround than doing it properly or am I wrong?

Comment: The DBMS enforces FK constraints. So, this is no workaround; this is a core part of programming databases with foreign keys.

Answer (score 1):

No need for another query : The result of an insert contain the last autoincrement insert id

This information is available with results.insertId.

So corrrection would be like :

```
connection.query(
      "Insert into users( user_name, user_password, user_type) values (?,?,?)",
      [customer.body.userName, customer.body.password, (userType = 1)],
      function(error, results, fields) {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
          return;
        }
        connection.query(
          "Insert into customers(user_id, cust_first_name, cust_last_name, cust_email, cust_city, cust_address, cust_zip_code, cust_state, cust_phone_num, cust_role, cust_website, cust_business_name) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",
          [
            results.insertId,
            customer.body.firstName,
            customer.body.lastName,
            customer.body.email,
            customer.body.city,
            customer.body.address,
            customer.body.zipCode,
            customer.body.state,
            customer.body.phoneNumber,
            (customer.body.custRole = 1),
            customer.body.website,
            customer.body.businessName
          ],
          function(error, results, fields) {
            if (error) {
              console.log(error);
            }
          }
        );
        res.end(JSON.stringify(results));
      }
    );
```

btw: the parameter userType=1 must probably be an error

Comment: Both O. Jones and yours work. As for the userType=1. I didn't design this part of the database and have no clue what its even used for. There are no notes left.

Comment: Use a MySQL client like HeidiSQL to view the database you inherited. Give the commands `SHOW CREATE TABLE users;` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE customers;`. You'll see the definitions of your tables.